# Trying to stop APNS custom sound from finishing playing

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

We are playing a custom when we deliver a push notification like so.

```
{
   "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "body" : "User 1 started a Meeting",
            "title" : "User 1 in New Topic"
        },
        "sound" : "ringConferenceStarted.wav"
    },
    "data" : {     
        "messageType" : "conference_started"
    }
}
```

The sound is about 26 seconds long.

Is there a way to end the sound early if we want to? We have looked into background pushes to send another one to stop it but it doesn't look like we end the playing with that method.

Answer (score 0):

In the Apple documentation it says:

> You can't modify silent notifications or those that only play a sound
> or badge the app's icon.

It seems that you need to update your notification strategy.

Comment: That does match what I have found so as well. I have looked into the Notification Service which lets you modify what is shown but doesn't look like it would work if I take out the alert and just leave a sound in the payload.

Comment: In such matters, it is very useful to look at the device logs from the console application. I tried :)